# Regex to retrieve text Inside the round bracket

Tags: regex

I want to retrieve text between the brackets. There are so many examples out here but none is giving accurate results.

For example, in this line:

```
Hello how are (you) doing ?
```

I want to retrieve just "you" which is inside the bracket.

I am using following regex: `/\((.*?)\)/` But this is giving me `(you)`.

Please let me know how to handle this.

Comment: Please also show your code so far. People cannot help you if they don't even know what language you are using and how your attempt looks like.

Comment: which programming language? You need to get the captured group and not the capture itself

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, you should be able to extract what you're looking for, which would be the first 'group' (i.e. the first thing in brackets) in this case. How to do this greatly depends on the language, but it's generally possible.

If this is not possible, if you don't know how (though maybe you want to figure that out), or as an alternative, you *may* be able to use look-around: (which may be less commonly supported though)

```
/(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))/
```

`(?<=...)` is look-behind, it looks at the previous characters.
`(?=...)` is look-ahead, it looks at the next characters.

The text matching look-behind and look-ahead aren't included in the actual match.

Comment: It is usually the case that there is a mechanism to get the matched groups. It is less common to have an engine that supports look-around.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i'd tackle this with JavaScript and Ruby:

```
# Ruby
text = "Hello how are (you) doing?"
pattern = /\(([^\(\)]+)\)/
puts text.match(pattern)[1]


// JavaScript
var text = "Hello how are (you) doing?";
var pattern = /\(([^\(\)]+)\)/;
console.log(text.match(pattern)[1]);
```

Comment: Note that you are changing the meaning somewhat with `\w+`.

Comment: Quite right. `\w+` will match only word characters. I'll update my answer with `/\(([^\(\)]+)\)/`, to match anything which isn't `(` or `)`.